# "We're sorry for the delay in reply." or "[...] delay in replying."?

Tags: grammaticality

There's an office debate going on over this. We're all non-native english speakers so none of us can make a good case for either option.

So, the debate goes on about whether the "delay in reply" construct is grammatically correct or not and, if it is, is it better or worse than "delay in replying" or "delay in our reply"?

Thank you!

Comment: "delay in reply" is plain wrong. "Please accept our apologies for the late reply/tardy response" is how I would put it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start with the following forms:

1. We're sorry for the delay in sending our reply to you.
2. We're sorry for the delay in replying to you.

Form 1 uses *reply* as a noun. You can remove *sending* and *to you* as they are both implied in the communication, but *reply* still requires a determiner. This leaves *We're sorry for the delay in **our** reply*.

Form 2 uses *replying* as a verb. Removing the implied *to you* leaves your second choice.

Therefore between your two expressions, use the second (*... delay in replying*).

Comment: But you could speak of  "a delayed reply".

Comment: @WS2 Indeed. Why ‘but’, though?

Comment: Not "a delay in reply" BUT "a delayed reply".

Answer (score 1):

"delay in reply" in not correct.  You would say "Sorry for the delay in replying" or "Sorry for the delay in our reply".  The first is more common.